# Looking to select image within list element and move it above the div with class="event-title"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

For each list element within the ul, I want to move the image within the div class="event-details" above the div with the class="event-title".

I'm having trouble with selections and inserting the image in the new place. I need to do this to achieve the styling I want as the wordpress Event plugin I'm using brings in preset HTML

index.html

```
<ul class="event-list-view">

  <li class="event 2017 2017april">
    <div class="event-date">
      <div class="start-date">
        <div class="event-weekday">Sat</div>
        <div class="event-day">01</div>
        <div class="event-month">Apr</div>
        <div class="event-year">2017</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="event-info single-day">
      <div class="event-title">
        <h3><a href="http://128sqnatc.org.uk/events/?event_id1=1">Swynnerton Camp 1</a></h3>
      </div>
      <span class="event-location">Swynnerton</span>
      <div class="event-details">
        <p><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-32" src="img/news1.png" alt="" width="1024" height="576" /></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia imperdiet velit, maximus gravida sem mollis vel. Pellentesque eu imperdiet leo, vitae viverra justo. Ut bibendum justo pellentesque tellus vulputate cursus. Cras dapibus porta neque, non porttitor mi dignissim eu. Nam orci magna, porta sed hendrerit in, mollis ac metus. In fringilla, leo ut suscipit porta, mauris turpis porttitor justo, imperdiet placerat nisl massa vitae urna.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="event 2017 2017april">
    <div class="event-date">
      <div class="start-date">
        <div class="event-weekday">Sun</div>
        <div class="event-day">02</div>
        <div class="event-month">Apr</div>
        <div class="event-year">2017</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-info single-day">
      <div class="event-title">
        <h3><a href="http://128sqnatc.org.uk/events/?event_id1=2">Swynnerton Camp 2</a></h3>
      </div>
      <span class="event-location">Swynnerton</span>
      <div class="event-details">
        <p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-112" src="img/dofe.png" alt="" width="553" height="369" /></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia imperdiet velit, maximus gravida sem mollis vel. Pellentesque eu imperdiet leo, vitae viverra justo. Ut bibendum justo pellentesque tellus vulputate cursus. Cras dapibus porta neque, non porttitor mi dignissim eu. Nam orci magna, porta sed hendrerit in, mollis ac metus. In fringilla, leo ut suscipit porta, mauris turpis porttitor justo, imperdiet placerat nisl massa vitae urna.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through each li with `each()` and move the image with `prepend()`:

```js
$(function() {
  // Loop each li
  $( "ul.event-list-view li" ).each(function( index ) { 
    // Move image into .event-info
    $(this).find(".event-info").prepend($(this).find(".event-details img"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="event-list-view">

  <li class="event 2017 2017april">
    <div class="event-date">
      <div class="start-date">
        <div class="event-weekday">Sat</div>
        <div class="event-day">01</div>
        <div class="event-month">Apr</div>
        <div class="event-year">2017</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="event-info single-day">
      <div class="event-title">
        <h3><a href="http://128sqnatc.org.uk/events/?event_id1=1">Swynnerton Camp 1</a></h3>
      </div>
      <span class="event-location">Swynnerton</span>
      <div class="event-details">
        <p><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-32" src="img/news1.png" alt="Image1" width="1024" height="576" /></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia imperdiet velit, maximus gravida sem mollis vel. Pellentesque eu imperdiet leo, vitae viverra justo. Ut bibendum justo pellentesque tellus vulputate cursus. Cras dapibus porta neque, non porttitor mi dignissim eu. Nam orci magna, porta sed hendrerit in, mollis ac metus. In fringilla, leo ut suscipit porta, mauris turpis porttitor justo, imperdiet placerat nisl massa vitae urna.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="event 2017 2017april">
    <div class="event-date">
      <div class="start-date">
        <div class="event-weekday">Sun</div>
        <div class="event-day">02</div>
        <div class="event-month">Apr</div>
        <div class="event-year">2017</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-info single-day">
      <div class="event-title">
        <h3><a href="http://128sqnatc.org.uk/events/?event_id1=2">Swynnerton Camp 2</a></h3>
      </div>
      <span class="event-location">Swynnerton</span>
      <div class="event-details">
        <p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-112" src="img/dofe.png" alt="Image2" width="553" height="369" /></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia imperdiet velit, maximus gravida sem mollis vel. Pellentesque eu imperdiet leo, vitae viverra justo. Ut bibendum justo pellentesque tellus vulputate cursus. Cras dapibus porta neque, non porttitor mi dignissim eu. Nam orci magna, porta sed hendrerit in, mollis ac metus. In fringilla, leo ut suscipit porta, mauris turpis porttitor justo, imperdiet placerat nisl massa vitae urna.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! Will keep your answer in mind for future use.